# BluetoothLEGatt sample codes in Android Studio to ON/OFF LED lights

Tags: android-studio, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm looking for a "simple" pair of an App written in Android Studio and code in mbed that work together, and allow: - send app to mbed (LED On/Off) - send mbed to app (Button Status) - notify mbed to app, (ring when button pressed)

Any pointers or guidance appreciated, and I'll make resulting mbed code and app source public here on mbed.

I've worked through several of the examples here on mbed (HTM, HTM, UART, more...), but have only used them with the Nordic sample Apps (nRF-MCP, Toolbox, etc.). Those Apps were written in an older Eclipse, and when imported into new Android Studio the result is quite cryptic code versus what a beginner needs. I've looked at Apps from other suppliers but they tend to use custom older libraries, not latest mbed, Android Studio, or Android SDK.

The only Android Studio sample code I've found for BLE is BlueToothLeGatt, it is a generic starting point to connect and list services, but nothing past that: http://developer.android.com/samples/BluetoothLeGatt/index.html.

Please Help Me. 
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it myself. Ohh

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == R.id.red_button) {
                if ((v.getTag() != null)
                        && (v.getTag() instanceof BluetoothGattCharacteristic)) {
                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic ch = (BluetoothGattCharacteristic) v
                            .getTag();
                     ch.setValue(new byte[] { (byte) 0x03 });
                    if (mConnGatt.readCharacteristic(ch)) {
                        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                    }
                }
```